# How do I list all the attributes of an object in python pdb?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I try to list all the attributes of an object in Python pdb.

Let's say I want to list all the attributes and all methods of `sys.stderr`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

For pdb, you should be able to do `p dir(a)`.

Comment: I doesn't work in pdb, it works in python shell, but not in pdb.

Comment: In my case I try to run this on `sys.stdout` and if fails with and exception from `file` object.

Comment: Is there a way to list everything in one column? Kind of like `ls -l` or `ls -1` in bash.

Comment: @hobbes3 that would be  `pp dir(a)`

Comment: @vxsx Don't you need to import pprint for that? https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html

Answer (score 10):

If a is your object, use `dir(a)` to get a list of its symbols. See the documentation about the `dir` function for more information.

Comment: both `print dir(a)` and `dir(a)` work in *my* `pdb`. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Problem already solved, but I'm using Python 2.5 on Windows. Maybe on newer versions print works by default.

Answer (score 7):

`print dir(object_name)` will list all the attributes of object for you.

Answer (score 4):

pdb is like a python shell, what you can do in pdb is what you can do in Python (except maybe some very exotic stuff)

You can set variables, call functions, ...

`dir` is the [right function to call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir). It should work on any objects as it can either default to the builtin or be implemented but I have indeed seen objects on which it fails. I guess it has to do with "old" python code (in my failing case : the `suds` library)

Usually `__dict__` can be of some help too on the pdb debugger